# Can I isolate only one property in a directive, with the rest mapped to the parent scope?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I created an angular directive to make generating forms easier.
It looks like this:

```
function formGroup() {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        replace: true,
        scope:
            {
                fields: "=fields",
            },
        templateUrl: "/WarpManufacturingProcessControl/Templates/InputForm.html",
    };
}
```

You pass in an array with info about the fields you want in the form and it generates it from a template that supports of number of input types.
Ex: 
The leftColumn array is mapped to "fields" in the scope of the directive.

I need to somehow pass in variables from the parent scope and bind them to the inputs in the form so that I can access the data in the form easily.

Right now, I pass something like `{label: "Name", type: "text"}` for each field. I want to include something like model: $scope.name and it bind to the input, is this possible?

The actual input looks like this inside an ng-repeat

```
<input type="text" ng-model="field.model" class="form-control" ng-if="field.type == 'text'" attributes="field.attrs" />
```

Right now I can go through the array and get the values (`$scope.leftColumn[0].model`), but this seems horrible.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up figuring out a solution that seems to work pretty well.

I added a second attribute to the directive where you pass an object that you want to store the form data in. Then you add an extra property to the form array with what you want to property to be named in the object.

Happy to share more details if anyone else runs across something like this